# how to avoid converting of tags present in the CDATA format

Tags: java, xml

I am putting the following value through CDATA while popoulating an xml,

```
<![CDATA[2 @#$*N 'STATE' ST]]>
```

But in the xml request generated i got the following result,

```
&lt;![CDATA[2 @#$*N 'STATE' ST]]&gt
```

So my question is how to avoid converting of `<` to `&lt` and `>` to `&gt`?
Please help

Answer (score 1):

I guess you used some XML library to do that. Just put in the raw string without the CDATA tagging. (i.e. "2 @#$*N 'STATE' ST") It is up to the library to decide how to represent the string value in the XML file.

It may quote special characters or it may use a CDATA section. The representation does not make a difference on the abstract value that is transported. In case it makes a difference for the receiver, the receiver is doing it wrong.